# apply jQuery function to table row but not first table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with multiple rows. Clicking each row will redirect the user to a unique url.
My problem is how can I apply click event on the table row but the td with action class should not be affected by the clickable row?
I tried the :not jQuery selector but unfortunately I am very new to jQuery. Thanks!

Here is my table:

```
<table id="tblHotel">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="sorting_disabled">&nbsp;</th>
        <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1" >
        <td class="actions">
            <a href="hotel/update/1"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the jQuery ajax:

```
$("#tblHotel tbody tr").click(function(){

var hotelid = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",                   
    url: "<?=site_url('hotel/view')?>/" + hotelid,
    success: function(data){
        $('.hiddenSidebar').html(data).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error!');
    }                       
});
}).not('tr td.actions');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//use td instead of tr and filter out td.actions
$("#tblHotel tbody td:not(.actions)").click(function(){

    var hotelid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",                   
        url: "<?=site_url('hotel/view')?>/" + hotelid,
        success: function(data){
            $('.hiddenSidebar').html(data).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error!');
        }                       
    });
})
```

or stop event propagation from `td.actions`

```
$("#tblHotel tbody td.actions").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Comment: what about the value of id for each tr? this has muliptle rows with unique id's..

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is clicked, try this:

```
$("#tblHotel tbody tr").click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('.actions')) return false;
    var hotelid = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",                   
        url: "<?=site_url('hotel/view')?>/" + hotelid,
        success: function(data){
            $('.hiddenSidebar').html(data).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error!');
        }                       
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to `return false` or use `e.stopPropagation()`, otherwise the event will bubble to the `TR` and the `.is()` check will fail.

Comment: problem is when I click the Edit link the alert('error!') keeps on popping up.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the ajax function now right? @markyorky

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri, not really.. The scenario is, clicking each row will redirect to a different url. each row is looped with unique id's.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tblHotel tbody tr").not('td.actions').click(function () {
    var hotelid = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=site_url('hotel/view')?>/" + hotelid,
        success: function (data) {
            $('.hiddenSidebar').html(data).show('slide', {
                direction: 'right'
            }, 300);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error!');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/gzq5X/1/)

And, if you're using jQuery-UI, your icon classes should look like this:

```
<table id="tblHotel">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">&nbsp;</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td class="actions"> <a href="hotel/update/1"><i class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" title="Edit"></i></a>
 <a href="#"><i class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" title="Delete"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```